# If else statement inside a for loop for a batch file

Tags: sql-server, for-loop

This for loop pulls a max int value from a SQL table, adds 1, then sets it equal to a variable called "Num".

How can I modify this for loop so that if there is no value found (or null entry) in the SQL column called "Number", it will set the variable `Num == 1`?

```
for /f "delims= " %%a in 
    ('sqlcmd -S SERVER -d DATABASE-Q "SET NOCOUNT ON; 
    select max(Number)+1 from TABLE"') do set Num=%%a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this from SQL statement. What you're looking for is `COALESCE`.

From [manual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)

> Evaluates the arguments in order and returns the current value of the first expression that initially does not evaluate to NULL.

Syntax for your case would be

```
select coalesce(max(Number)+1, 1) FROM TABLE
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something stupid easy but I was having brain block.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select max(isnull (number,0))+1 from table
```

Edited